# Convert or extract value from input to plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this js function that converts ALL input values into text.
I want to convert only ONE row from to plain text (all rows have 5 cells plus a button for saving) and with that button i want to convert that row data into plain text. I was trying to use .closest object but i failed.

```
 function disable_inp() {
    $("tr:gt(0) td:has(input)").text(function() {
      return $('input', this).val();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Array to string conversion...

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`:eq` selector?](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: Post your HTML as well. Also, you wanna do this only on the first row and not on any others?

Comment: yes, i know about that selector

Comment: i want to do this in the row where the button is placed. i'm using arrays for creating the row. I can put the html later, i'm writing from my phone now and that js function is the only thing i remember.

Comment: and obviously all rows have an edit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `:eq` and not `:gt`. The `eq` gets the index of the selection, while `gt` is greater than.

```
function disable_inp() {
  $("tr:eq(0) td:has(input)").text(function() {
    return $('input', this).val();
  });
}
```

And with the button, you can do the same:

```
$("button").click(function disable_inp() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:has(input)").text(function() {
    return $('input', this).val();
  });
});
```

Here, the `.closest()` will find the first parent that matches the selection and applies from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.click(function(){
    var $row = $(this).parent().parent(); //assuming it's not wrapped this will be the <tr>
    $row.find("td").each(function(){
        var plaintext = $(this).text();
        // do stuff with the plaintext
    });
});
```

Comment: It's better to write the explanation outside.